# %f rounds the numbers

Tags: python, printing, integer, numbers, rounding

I'm writing a code to calculate the average of values for every key and then print it, but when I use %f in print() it rounds the number, so instead of 6.066666666666666 I get 6.066667. I want it to print the original number without rounding it. how can I fix this?
thanks in advance

```
for i in range(0, n):
    print('%s,%f' %(ord_list[i][0], ord_list[i][1]))
```

also, I know I can do this, but this print the key and average with a space in between I want there to only be a comma

```
for i in range(0, n):
     print(ord_list[i][0], ord_list[i][1])
```

full code just in case

```
import csv
from statistics import mean 
from collections import OrderedDict

with open('grades.txt', 'r') as f_handle:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f_handle)
    dct = OrderedDict()
    dct = {row[0]: row[1:] for row in csv_reader}
    dct = {k:[int(i) for i in v] for k,v in dct.items()}
    ord_dic = OrderedDict()
    for k,vals in dct.items():
        for_dic = {k : mean(vals)}
        ord_dic.update(for_dic)

 
ord_dic = {k: v for k, v in sorted(ord_dic.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}

ord_list = sorted(ord_dic.items(), key=lambda t: t[::-1])
print(ord_list)
n = len(ord_list)

for i in range(0, n):
    print('%s,%f' %(ord_list[i][0], ord_list[i][1]))
```

Comment: you want it to round to 7, or 6.07? i am unsure what you are asking here

Comment: you want don't round your number?

Comment: i don't want it to get rounded, i want to print the original number @SeanPowell

Comment: @Farzan By default, python prints only 6 remainder digits, so you may need to use `%.15lf`

Comment: "i want to print the original number" <- The value that's stored is exactly `6.066666666666666429819088079966604709625244140625`. That's the value that would be printed if no rounding is applied. Are you sure that's what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use f-strings in this case.

Use the print statement as below

```py
print(f" {ord_list[i][0]}, {ord_list[i][1]}")
```

Using %f converts it to float (but your number is actually double) and reduces precision.

Comment: You can read more about precision, numpy.floats etc. in Python.

Answer (score 0):

You can print a float without rounding by doing the following

```
print "{0:.15f}".format(a)
```

where the 15f would indicate how many numbers after the decimal point you would like.